# How to set ipfs's Addresses.API

Tags: go-ethereum, dapps, nft, ipfs

When I set Address.API to 0.0.0.0, I get an error.
How does it work?
I deploy ipfs gateway, on my server, I need to set the value of Address.API to 0.0.0.0, in order to be able to access webui.
[image]

Comment: see that: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15778/ipfs-access-via-port-5001?rq=1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.